# see dependency tree for module/factory in angular

Tags: angularjs, dependency-injection, dependencies

Here's the problem. I have a `someModuleA` that has access to `theFactoryOfInterestX`:

```
angular.module('someModuleA', ['someModuleB', 'someModuleC', ... /*someModuleZ not here*/])

.controller('controllerFromA', ['theFactoryOfInterestX', , function(theFactoryOfInterestX) {
    console.log(theFactoryOfInterestX); // that factory is available here
}]);
```

I know for a fact that `theFactoryOfInterestX` is only defined in `someModuleZ`:

```
angular.module('someModuleA', [/*stuff*/])

.factory('theFactoryOfInterestX', [function() { /*definition*/ }]);
```

So, is it clear that the dependent modules `['someModuleB', 'someModuleC', ...]` of `someModuleA`, must at some point of time depend on `someModuleZ`? If yes, this is a surprising fact and I need to investigate how the dependency leads to `someModuleZ`. How can I do it? Is there a way to see the dependency graph of angular?

Comment: Please, specify the context for the question. Why exactly do you need this information?

Comment: @estus like I said, I don't think `someModuleZ` should be there. I want to figure out why `someModuleZ` is included

Comment: Maybe the real module names would make more sense than alphabet. But usually you inspect source code and figure out who's who, it never hurts to get the hands dirty. Angular stores this info internally (it is possible to get module hierarchy from the outside but service data is private). Angular has to be hacked to access this information, [like that](https://chrome.google.com/webstore/detail/angularjs-graph/gghbihjmlhobaiedlbhcaellinkmlogj?hl=en).